New voting buttons make it hard to distinguish voted upon posts on MAIN site
The new voting buttons have made it significantly more difficult to see whether the user has already voted on a post. I’m aware that on other sites the filled-in background after voting is a different color with a better contrast (including now our meta site), but in our main site’s styling, it is hard to see.
Would it be possible that the voting button background could be amended in some fashion on the voted posts for our main site styling?


Update 2023-08-02:
I just saw this color scheme on a different part of Stack Exchange. Perhaps something like this could work well on our main site using “Bitcoin Orange”.

Update 2023-10-30:
The new color scheme that was launched recently appears to improve the situation slightly by making the background on the voted button darker (before, not-voted, after):



It seems to me that the contrast could still be more pronounced.

I assume this is about the voting buttons on the main site (and not on Meta, which has already been adjusted)?

@V2Blast: Yes, I noticed the issue on the main site.

Thanks. This issue is already on our radar via the MSE post I can't see if I've already voted on something, so I've linked the ticket for this post to the existing issue for that (so we can hopefully respond to this post as well if/when that gets addressed).

Ah excellent. Thank you very much for your help, @V2Blast

@V2Blast: This user interface issue on our main site still persists. Any chance that you have an update?

No updates at this time, but we'll make sure to let you know when we have something to share.

Thanks @V2Blast

A fix has been now deployed. A button indicating a prior vote now has a significantly darker styling. Screenshot from the main page:

